# How can I fetch more than one attribute from a serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

My models have multiple attributes, all of which are being serialized.

According to the user's request, I want my API to return only limited information

This is my model's code

```
from django.db import models
  
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

This is my Serializer's code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User
  
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is my View's code

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import JsonResponse

@api_view(['GET'])
def viewUsers(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return JsonResponse({'id': serializer.data['id'], 'name': serializer.data['name']})
```

The code below works if I want to return a single attribute/field

```
return JsonResponse(serializer.data['id'])
```

but when I try to fetch more than one attribute by the dictionary method, it throws this error

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I suggest that you read more about `ModelViewSet` in Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 1):

`many=True` passed to `UserSerializer` indicates that `serializer.data` will contain a `list` of `dict`s where each particular `dict` will be a result of serializing `User` instance to expected `dict`

Taking into account `serializer.data` is a list then if you try to   execute `serializer.data['id']` it raises

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

You may want to update the `return` statement to

```py
return JsonResponse([{'id': item['id'] for item in  serializer.data}])
```

or specify that you expect only `id` field to be returned by the serializer

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id",)
```

and then in the view

```py
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```